# How does Builders<TA>.Update.Set() handle parallel access?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Assuming 'items' (provided as a parameter in the Set() method below) is defined as List (TM is some structure type, i.e. made of properties only) containing **only one item**, and 10 processes trying to write simultaneously an update to `items` (**without** adding anything to the List):

```
Builders<TK>.Update.Set("Items", items);
```

An update means that there is at least one element in the BSON with a modified **value**.

What will MongoDB in such case?

Will it eventually overwrite with the last process into that **single** element (leaving that List with a single element)?

Or will it **add** 10 such elements (items) into that List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how doesit work with parallel access. But [Set operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) always overwrite value with an inserted.

To add new values to an array you should  use [addToSet operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)  (it adds only new values) or [push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

You could access them as Builders too:

```
Builders<TA>.Update.AddToSet
Builders<TA>.Update.Push
```

Comment: Thanks +1. I am actually interested in the overwrite behavior. The reason I am asking my question is that for some strange reason, the Set operator *adds* instead of overwrites. Weird.

Comment: @datps Do you have sample code? From my understanding that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Turns out it indeed cannot happen. The bug was elsewhere, in the original MongoDB documents to begin with. So much for inheriting other people's fruit of labor...